# Error: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

Tags: ionic2

I am using Ionic 2, and have just moved some pages from one project to another, now I get the error below at run-time.

If anyone can advise, I would appreciate it.

> ```
> Error: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
>     at Object.typescriptSourcemapLoaderMemory (E:\Development\IDE\ionic-apps\firebase-chat-master\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\webpack\typescript-sourcemap-loader-memory.js:21:34)
> ```

More info:

> ```
> Your system information:
>
>  ordova CLI: 6.4.0
> Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
> Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
> ios-deploy version: Not installed
> ios-sim version: Not installed
> OS: Windows 10
> Node Version: v6.9.2
> Xcode version: Not installed
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it seemed to be an issue with either the Angular CLI or Ionics webpack config.

Anyway, updating to RC4 seemed to do the trick: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

I also updated the app scripts to 1.0.0:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md